# Flutter how to update list in firebase document

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to update a field on firebase from my flutter app but it doesn't work.

activities is an array, 0 a map.
[image]

I want to update 'daysdone' with 'val' from my flutter app.

```
ChipsChoice<String>.multiple(
                                            value: activities
                                                .elementAt(i)
                                                .daylistdone,
                                            onChanged: (val) =>
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                    .collection(
                                                        widget.user.user.uid)
                                                    .doc(documentName)
                                                    .set({
                                              "activities." + i.toString(): {
                                                'title': activities
                                                    .elementAt(i)
                                                    .title,
                                                'days': activities
                                                    .elementAt(i)
                                                    .daylist,
                                                'daysdone': val,
                                                'daysbool': activities
                                                    .elementAt(i)
                                                    .daybool,
                                                // 'daysdonebool': myData2bool2,
                                                'notification': activities
                                                    .elementAt(i)
                                                    .notification,
                                                'time':
                                                    activities.elementAt(i).time
                                              },
                                            }),
                                            choiceItems: C2Choice.listFrom<
                                                String, String>(
                                              source: activities
                                                  .elementAt(i)
                                                  .daylist,
                                              value: (i, v) => v,
                                              label: (i, v) => v,
                                            ),
                                          ),
```

It gives me this result
[image]

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first image is a list of maps. The only way you can update the field `daysdone` is by accessing the entire list, and then traversing through the list to your desired map position (in the first image case, this should be position 0), then editing that particular map. After doing this, you have to update the entire activities field:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').doc('Mydocument').update({'activities': newEditedList})
```

I would personally recommend a complete re-structure of your database-collection. Like the following:

**Step 1**

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2: Each user has sub-collection: Activities**

[image: Step 2: Each user has sub-collection: Activities]

**Step 3: Each activity can now easily be accessed**

[image: Step 3: Each activity can now easily be accessed]

To access a user's activities:

```dart
var result 
 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyUsers').doc(widget.user.user.uid).collection('Activities').limit(20).get(GetOptions(source:Source.server));
```

If you want to update color field:

```dart
// Color
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyUsers').doc(widget.user.user.uid).update({'color':'red'});
```

If you want to update an activity :

```dart
//days done
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyUsers').doc(widget.user.user.uid).collection('Activities').doc('the_activityId').update({'daysdone': "value"});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It sounds like a good idea. Is there any way you can help me with this?

Comment: I have been trying to fix this issue for a month.

Comment: What part do you need help with